# Why slots in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

I'm studying Qt library. Recently I hit the concept of `slots` and so far I understand them as functions that are executed as reactions to certain events. Is it only this or something more?

Why did they choose such an exotic name [slots](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slot) for something such ordinary? This word has so many meanings. Which meaning did they intend to thought about `slots` in Qt?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms `signal` and `slot` are somewhat mismatched.

A better choice might have been `signal` and `receiver`, or `connector` and `slot`.

In C++, a signal can only connect to a function that has been defined as a slot. Trying to connect a signal to an ordinary function would be like trying to connect a usb cable to an ethernet port.

However, in PyQt, this distinction is much less important, because *any* callable can be connected to a signal, not just predefined slots.

Having said that, more recent versions of PyQt also provide a [pyqtSlot decorator](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) which can be used to define a slot with several different signatures. And in general, in PyQt it is more efficient to connect to a predefined slot (whether C++ or PyQt) than to an ordinary python callable.

For full details of the signal and slot support in PyQt, see the [reference guide](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: But what led them to choose a word `slot`? Some funny story or accident?

Comment: @xralf. The meaning of `slot` they intended is probably closest to the first one in the dictionary link you provided: i.e. an aperture that receives something: like a keyhole, or ... (well, use your imagination ;-) I guess they might also have been looking for a word that began with the same letter as `signal`.

Comment: This sounds unlogical for me. Why function should be receiver? Function is the action that is fired when some signal occurs. Every action is caused by some signal.

Comment: @xralf. No. Signals are emitted completely independently of whether they are connected to anything; they do not necessarily cause anything to happen. A slot is merely a local receiver that is listening for a broadcast signal. The action it takes is completely independent of any signal it may receive (it could be listening for many different signals, or none). The "action" of a signal is the message it broadcasts; nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Slots go with signals. You connect signals to slots. This is a core concept in Qt itself, it is not specific to PyQt.

The Qt documentation has the details: [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html).

It's just a very handy concept, makes for rather clean separation of layers in your code.

The slots themselves are plain functions (in C++), you can use them as normal functions as well as as "signal receivers".

Comment: The following linked picture showing operators insert plug-in into different slots to connect signal to intended lines may help understand the concept of signal & slot. Like in this line of codes, "connect" is a keyword: self.input_V_bt.clicked.connect(self.file_open_mp4), https://ar.pinterest.com/pin/160300067968728580/?autologin=true